# Images have stopped appearing in my webapp

Tags: image, web-applications

I am a teacher (not an experienced developer) and have written a few web apps that draw data from google sheets spreadsheets and summarise in a nice easy to view way.  The web apps have all been running very smoothly for a number of months.  Yesterday evening however the images have stopped appearing.

These images are sat in the google sheet in the form https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=(then the ID).  I had also tried them as https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=(then the ID).  They are then Vlookup'd to the main spreadsheet.  The web app then collects the image and some other data from the spreadsheet and displays it in the web app.

There have been no changes to the school network, I have cleared my cache and my cookies numerous times (this worked on a similar issue before), the code has not been changed at all.  But now my images have been replaced with a small rectangular icon that looks to be an stock image of the grass a cloud and the sky (very cut off though).

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

If it helps, this is an snippet of my search and return from my code.gs

```
function searchAndReturnData(Names) {
  Logger.log('Search Query: ' + Names);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("count");
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:G" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var results = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] === Names) { // Check for a match in column B (index 0)
      var name = data[i][0];
      var imageUrl = data[i][2]; // Assuming column H (index 6) contains the image URLs
      var comment = data[i][3]; // Assuming column I (index 8) contains the comments
       var sessionsAttended = data[i][6]; // Assuming column G (index 5) contains the sessions attended
      var pointsFromPods = data[i][5]; // Assuming column F (index 4) contains the points from pods
      results.push({ Name: name, ImageUrl: imageUrl, Comment: comment, SessionsAttended: sessionsAttended,
        PointsFromPods: pointsFromPods });
      break;
    }
  }
```

Then this is my display result from my Index.html

````
`function displayResult(results) {
  var outputDiv = $("#output");

  if (results.length > 0) {
    var htmlContent = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      htmlContent += '<div class="result-item">';
      htmlContent += '<img src="' + results[i].ImageUrl + '" style="max-width: 200px;">';
      htmlContent += '<div class="comment">' + results[i].Comment + '</div>';
      htmlContent += '</div>';
      your text
```'


I tried deleting all of my cache and cookies, since that worked before.  I have checked all of my image sharing settings in google drive
````

Comment: Interestingly another thing I have noticed is that the images are actually there. When I click on the "holding Icon" thing (hill, blue sky and a cloud) and click open image in a new tab it opens the image.  The issue is it is not being displayed...

Comment: Also on inspection all of my images are running into a 403 error.  With strict-origin-when-cross-origin.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, I have found an answer on another question that provides a work around. It sounds like it is a CORS issue.  This is due to a new change by google on 11/1/24.  To work around it and allow images to display they said to change images to a thumbnail since then there are less issues.  So I changed my image URL from "us......download?......." to "thumbnail?id"  Hope this helps you too